# executing a command line in codeigniter - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, shell

I have a `Codeigniter` framework on place, which I'm building a test framework on top of it.
Once of the features of the test framework is to remotely deploy test suits. Therefore, I'm trying to deploy a `Python` test suit I wrote from the webpage:

```
public function deploy_test()
{
    if( !$this->input->is_cli_request() ) {
       echo json_encode(system("python test_suit.py"));
    }
}
```

from my controller, so, when a test deployed, I want to run it. For proof of concept I did that way. However, the job never get deployed, nor is the command line ever executed.
When I ran that piece of code from the terminal, it works as supposed. What am I missing here?
Thank you

** Its curious to mention when I execute `ls -l` it works ...

Comment: Does the web-user (`www`, `apache`, etc.) have permissions to run that file (and to do the things that the script needs to do)? Also, are you absolutely sure the path is correct?

Comment: permission is `755`. The absolute path is correct ... I'm executing with full path

Comment: @jeroen it does not want to execute python somehow ... even `python --version` isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a bad idea - if the host has declined access to executing things on the server (after all, how does it know that your code is not malicious), you really shouldn't try to work around this, at least without speaking to your provider and asking them if they're ok for you to do this!

After all, executing an LS isn't really going to be malicious, but you could try and execute a Python script that 'rm -rf's the server.

Now, you might be able to find a work around, but to my mind, the question is should you? They might interpret this as a hacking attempting.

Comment: I wrote everything Russ ... and the server is a local server, which is mine ... do you have a better way to do so?

Comment: Ah ok - well my point still stands, although the context changes :) Have you checked out the Log files from when this executes ? (assuming linux) http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-log-files-location-and-how-do-i-view-logs-files/